# Justification for $\operatorname{dim} \wedge^k(V)$ is $n\choose k$ the alternating $k$-linear form.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

I was told that: $\operatorname{dim} \wedge^k(V)$ is $n\choose k.$ and I am trying to justify this by computing it for different dimensions of $V.$

If $\operatorname{dim}(V) = 1,$ then $v_1 \wedge v_1 = 0$. Therefore, $\operatorname{dim} \wedge^1(V)$ is $1\choose 1$

If $\operatorname{dim}(V) = 2,$ then we will have the following cases:

\begin{align*}
    v_1 \wedge v_1 &= 0\\
    v_1 \wedge v_2 &= -  v_2 \wedge v_1\\
     v_2 \wedge v_1 &= -  v_1 \wedge v_2\\
      v_2 \wedge v_2 &= 0
\end{align*}

But then I can not conclude what is my $k$ in this case and how many variables actually I am choosing as I have the second case is just the same as the third case. Could anyone help me in this please?

Also, I know that

\begin{align*}
    v_1 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_1 &= 0\\
    v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 &= -  v_2 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_3\\
&= -  v_3 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_1\\
&= - v_1 \wedge v_3 \wedge v_2\\
&= v_2 \wedge v_3 \wedge v_1\\
&= v_3 \wedge v_1 \wedge v_2\\
     v_2 \wedge v_2 \wedge v_2  &= 0\\
      v_3 \wedge v_3  \wedge v_3 &= 0
\end{align*}

But I do not know how to translate this into $n \choose k.$ Could someone help me in this also?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Note that I was told that my question maybe a duplicate of this [If $V$ is $k$-dimensional then show that $\dim \wedge^n V = \binom {k} {n}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4019943/if-v-is-k-dimensional-then-show-that-dim-wedgen-v-binom-k-n) but I do not agree with this as I need a small and concrete example to be calculated not an abstract procedure as in the previous link and the other one is asking about a specific case when $k<n$ in $k \choose n$ which is not my case.

Comment: $n = \dim V$ and $k$ is the number of vectors being wedged together. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: If $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, then
\begin{align*}
    \{e_{i_1} \wedge e_{i_2} \wedge \ldots \wedge e_{i_n} : 1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_n \leq k\}
\end{align*}
is a basis for $\bigwedge^n V$. See the duplicate (I think this is an answer. Try to fill in the details).

Comment: You seems to be computing various cases where $\dim(V)=n = k$. In every example you give you've (almost) shown that the dimension is $\binom{n}{n}=1$. Try in 3 dimensions, but compute the dimension of the second exterior power.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Ok, I think I am getting your point, so in my $n = 2,$ still I am choosing 2 of 2? If so, I can not see this, could you explain more please?

Comment: I think that what @Jaimie is getting at is, e.g., if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis of $V^3$, then $\Lambda^2 V$ has elements given as linear combinations of wedges of **two** $v_i$, not $3$.  So, $v_1\wedge v_2 \in \Lambda^2 V$.  In contrast, in your three examples, you've picked $k = n$ in all $3$:  That is, when there were three $v_i$, you only considered $\Lambda^3 V$, where you wedge three $v_i$ together.

Comment: @JasonDeVito what is the exterior product of a single vector then?

Comment: I think of $\Lambda^1 V$ as being canonically isomorphic to $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is a basis for $V$ then for

- $k = 1$, we have $v_1, \dots, v_n$ as a basis for $\bigwedge^1V = V$ (definition)
- $k = 2$, we have $\{v_i \wedge v_j : i < j\}$ as a basis for $\bigwedge^2 V$
- $k = 3$, we have $\{v_i \wedge v_j \wedge v_l : i < j < l\}$ as a basis for $\bigwedge^3 V$.

and so forth. By definition, $k$ is the number of vectors you see in each expression. So $v_1$ is $k = 1$ since there is one vector in the expression; $v_1 \wedge v_2$ is $k = 2$ since there are two vectors, and so forth.

You said you understand that $v_i \wedge v_j = - v_j \wedge v_i$ and $v_i \wedge v_j \wedge v_l = v_j \wedge v_l \wedge v_i =$ etc. so I won't belabour that point.

Imagine $\dim V = 3$ and $k = 2$. Then a general vector in $V$ looks like $av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3$ and you can expand, for example
$$(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3) \wedge v_2 = a (v_1 \wedge v_2) + b (v_2 \wedge v_2) + c(v_3 \wedge v_2) = a (v_1 \wedge v_2) - c (v_2 \wedge v_3)$$

Using the identities $v_i \wedge v_i = 0$ and $v_j \wedge v_i = - v_i \wedge v_j$.

If you expand $(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3) \wedge (a'v_1 + b'v_2 + c'v_3)$ and collect terms, you will get some linear combination of $v_1 \wedge v_2, v_1 \wedge v_3, v_2 \wedge v_3$. (First expand one side, then the other.)

Next there is the combinatorial identity: $\#\{(i, j) : i < j\} = \#\{\{i, j\} : i \neq j \} = \binom{n}{2}$ because given a set of numbers like $\{5, 3\}$ there is exactly one way to create an increasing sequence $3 < 5$ out of it. Therefore increasing sequences of length $k$ and subsets of size $k$ are equinumerous.

Comment: a minor issue: for $k=3$, it's probably best to use a letter other than $k$ as the index in $v_i\wedge v_j\wedge v_k$ (e.g $v_a\wedge v_b\wedge v_c$ where $1\leq a<b<c\leq n$).

Comment: Do you have  know of a good book explaining this concept?

Comment: @Brain I think I first learned about wedge products from Munkres's differential geometry book (Analysis on Manifolds). For an algebraic focus, any (graduate) algebra book should contain a chapter or so on this. Also Keith Conrad has some notes: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf

Answer (score 1):

How many totally antisymmetric tensors of rank $k$ exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$? We will take a combinatorial approach. Call the tensor $T_{i_1 i_2 ... i_k}$. If any of the $i_m$ are equal, then this component of $T$ is necessarily $0$, since interchanging any two indices flips the sign of their respective components. There are $k$ indices, each of which must take each of $1, ..., n$ distinct values (since the component of the tensor is determined as $0$ otherwise). So the amount of ways to choose a subset of size $k$ from $n$ is $^nC_k$. This means that the dimension of the $k$-th exterior power is $^nC_k$ (in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Hopefully this provides some intuition that you are looking for.